# How to partition by an expression

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to partition by an expression instead of a field. Take this query

```
SELECT 
      ID,
      Value,
      Status,
      SUM(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS "Sum",
      COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Status = 'Ready') AS ReadyCount --Error here
FROM TestAggregation
```

I need to get the ReadyCount that is grouped Status but only need the count to apply to status that is ready. Is this possible?

Comment: I deleted that comment after reviewing the docs for the OVER clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a conditional sum instead:

```
SELECT 
      ID,
      Value,
      Status,
      SUM(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS "Sum",
      SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Ready' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS ReadyCount --Error here
FROM TestAggregation
```